# Issues getting A* pathfinding to work

Tags: c++, arrays, a-star

I have a problem with my A* Pathfinding algorithm.

I'm fairly new to C++ programming and am trying to navigate an actor through a map grid in the form of a 2d array.

I've been trying this for a few days now, but to no avail. I've looked up countless tutorials and other C++ code and tried to mould it to my specifications and I am unable to get the result.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Apologies for the vagueness of the question, there is no -specific- issue, the problem is that the code seems to pick random tiles from the openlist and never returns a correct value.

Sorry for the spaghetti code as well.

Thanks in advance

main.cpp

```
int moveCostG(int x, int y, int dx, int dy) {
    int g = (abs(dx - x) + abs(dy - y));
    return g;
}

int moveCostH(int dx, int dy, int nx, int ny){
    int h = (abs(nx - dx) + abs(ny - dy));
    return h;
}

int moveCostF(int x, int y, int dx, int dy, int nx, int ny) {
    return (moveCostG(x, y, dx, dy) + moveCostH(dx, dy, nx, ny));
}

bool searchList(std::vector<coordList> n_list, int search_term_x, int search_term_y) {
    int size = sizeof(n_list)/sizeof(coordList);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if ((n_list[i].x == search_term_x) && (n_list[i].y == search_term_y)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void pathfinding(int x, int y, int nx, int ny) {
    //x, y = current location
    //dx, dy = changed location
    //nx, ny = location to go to
    int size = 0;
    int dx = x;
    int dy = y;
    bool found = false;

    //boolMap is a 2d adjacency matrix that represents whether or not a tile
    //is passable.
    //0 = Passable, 1 = NOT passable
  int boolMap[MAX_X][MAX_Y];
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++) {
      if (!map[i][j].layer1.passable || !map[i][j].layer2.passable) {
        boolMap[i][j] = 1;
      }
      else {
        boolMap[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

    //Creating lists
    std::vector<coordList> openList;
    std::vector<coordList> closedList;

    //Adding starting location to closed list
    coordList current;
    current.x = x;
    current.y = y;
    current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx, dy, nx, ny);
    closedList.push_back(current);

    //Pushing a placeholder to list so search function works
    openList.push_back(current);

    //Adding next door neighbours
    current.x = dx + 1;
    current.y = dy;
    current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx + 1, dy, nx, ny);
    if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
        if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
            //found in closed -- ignore it
        }
        else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
            openList.push_back(current);
            size++;
        }
    }

    current.x = dx - 1;
    current.y = dy;
    current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx - 1, dy, nx, ny);

    if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
        if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
            //found in closed -- ignore it
        }
        else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
            openList.push_back(current);
            size++;
        }
    }

    current.x = dx;
    current.y = dy + 1;
    current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx, dy + 1, nx, ny);

    if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
        if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
            //found in closed -- ignore it
        }
        else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
            openList.push_back(current);
            size++;
        }
    }

    current.x = dx;
    current.y = dy - 1;
    current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx, dy - 1, nx, ny);

    if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
        if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
            //found in closed -- ignore it
        }
        else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
            openList.push_back(current);
            size++;
        }
    }

    //Removing placeholder of openList
    openList.erase(openList.begin());

    //--- NOW ALL INITIAL SQUARES HAVE BEEN CALCULATED
    bool first_time = true;
    //While?
    while (found == false) {
        if (first_time == false) {

            //Add new walkable tiles
            current.x = dx + 1;
            current.y = dy;
            current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx + 1, dy, nx, ny);
            if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
                if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
                    //found in closed -- ignore it
                }
                else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
                    openList.push_back(current);
                    size++;
                }
            }

            current.x = dx - 1;
            current.y = dy;
            current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx - 1, dy, nx, ny);

            if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
                if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
                    //found in closed -- ignore it
                }
                else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
                    openList.push_back(current);
                    size++;
                }
            }

            current.x = dx;
            current.y = dy + 1;
            current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx, dy + 1, nx, ny);

            if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
                if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
                    //found in closed -- ignore it
                }
                else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
                    openList.push_back(current);
                    size++;
                }
            }

            current.x = dx;
            current.y = dy - 1;
            current.f = moveCostF(x, y, dx, dy - 1, nx, ny);

            if (boolMap[current.x][current.y] == 0){ //Check if tile is passable
                if (searchList(closedList, current.x, current.y) == true) {
                    //found in closed -- ignore it
                }
                else if (searchList(openList, current.x, current.y) == false){
                    openList.push_back(current);
                    size++;
                }
            }

        }

        first_time = false;

        //Setting lowest to high number so first result is always lower
        int lowest = 999999999;
        int lowest_place;

        //Finding lowest F value
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (openList[i].f < lowest){
                lowest = openList[i].f;
                lowest_place = i;
            }
        }

        //Adding the lowest to the closed list
        closedList.push_back(openList[lowest_place]);
        //Removing lowest from open list
        openList.erase(openList.begin() + lowest_place);
        size--;

        //Checking if next location is the location is the destination
        dx = openList[lowest_place].x;
        dy = openList[lowest_place].y;
        if ((dx == nx) && (dy == ny)) {
            printf("FOUND IT!");
            found = true;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Class used:

```
class coordList{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int f;
    coordList();
};
```

Comment: `Sorry for the spaghetti code as well.`  Well, Don't post it then... fix it before you post - you'll probably find the error when you clean it up

Comment: `sizeof(n_list)` won't tell you the length of the vector `n_list`. Use `n_list.size()`. The `sizeof` of a `std::vector` is constant regardless of it's contents.

Comment: Understanding how to effectively use a debugger is an essential skill for developing in c++. Take some time to familiarize yourself with a debugger for whatever platform you are developing on.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @UKMonkey Apologies didn't mean to cause upset ^^

Comment: @B.Shnrub I'm not upset ;)  I'm just trying to highlight to you that you know your code is poor, and that you have a problem.  The problem is hidden in the poor code; and the easiest way to resolve it is to remove the hiding places of the bug!  If you write clear and understandable code - then you're less likely to write bugs!